# FireBase signInWithEmailAndPassword not doing anything

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Starting to write an application using Android Studio, I ran into a problem regarding the firebase login command. The application is connected to firebase and the user list contains the provided strings for 'mail' and 'pw'. The method 'login()' should return one of both messages, but nothing is happening (not even an error message in the log). The code is given below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    Dialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            logIn();
        }
    }

    private void logIn() {
        String mail = "example@gmail.com";
        String pw = "password";
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pw)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                       @Override
                       public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           } else {
                               Log.w("Sign in error: ", task.getException());
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                           }
                       }
                   });    
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe define `mail` and `pw`? else an `OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>` might never happen.

Comment: I did that already, now also edited into the code above

Comment: and you are certain neither of them are `NULL`; maybe set a break-point?

Comment: yes definitely, no break-point also

Comment: nope, you should set a break-point at `firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword()` and inspect the values, step further into to the next break-point, eg. `onComplete()`. this answer states the installed `play-services` as a possible reason:

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work, the Google Play services-version is 11.7.43 and I think it is up to date.

Comment: the current version is `12.8.74`, that's at least what I have installed. you might have to update device/emulator; build against Play Services Library & Firebase `15.0.0` +

Comment: awesome! I was first trying updating but nothing worked. Now that I built a new emulator using the newest sdk-version, it is working. Thanks a lot!